# Ionic2 DatePicker expression inside ngModel

Tags: angular, datepicker, ionic2

I have just installed this extention into my project; https://github.com/misha130/datepicker-ionic2

all goes well, but the results of the module is piped like that `date | date`
and i get short date like `Jan 8, 2017` and I want this value to be inside `HerdDate` variable.

look on my [GIT](https://github.com/eshk12/Parabi/blob/Herd-Component-Created/src/pages/Herd-Component/AddHerd/AddHerd.html).

I'm looking for a way that I can insert that expression `date|date` into the var `HerdDate`, How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried with something like {{ dateObj | date:'longDate' }}

Comment: I want to bind `date | date` results into `HerdDate`

Answer (score 0):

AddHerd.html

```
    <ion-item full="true" ion-datepicker type="text" (ionChanged)="date = $event">
      <ion-label stacked>תאריך הגעה:</ion-label>
      <ion-input [(ngModel)]="HerdDate" [value]="date | date"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

AddHerd.ts

```
  public HerdDate: Date;
  public date: Date = new Date();
```